# Navigating through a big numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a big `numpy.ndarray` that I need to process. I want to learn how to navigate through the data. In the following is just a small set of it.
I tried to solve the problem by using multiple `for` – loops and slicing but somehow I got confused.
Can you help me to solve the tasks at the end?

Columns:

```
group;subgroup;value
1;1;356
1;2;403
1;3;370
2;2;488
2;3;568
2;4;562
2;5;478
3;1;415
3;2;418
3;3;388
3;4;414
```

Task: Per group divide each value by the value corresponding to the smallest subgroup.
So I have to

1. Find out how many groups (column 0) are in the array. Here: 3
2. Find out how many subgroups per each value exist and where to find the smallest subgroup per group. Here: eg. group 1 has 3 subgroups. 1 being the smallest.
3. Divide all the subgroups values by the value of the smallest one and insert it into the array. Here will result in 1;1;(356/256) then 1;2;(402/356)...

Comment: What have you tried? And what do you expect in terms of a valid `np.ndarray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is a great tool for this, it's all numpy underneath so you can just take your `numpy.ndarray` and convert it into a pandas data frame by calling the `pandas.DataFrame()` method on it. Here is an example you can run in your terminal:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Dict to Turn into Dataframe
data = {
    "group": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    "subgroup": [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    "value": [356, 403, 370, 488, 568, 562, 478, 415, 418, 388, 414]
}

# Convert to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
normed = []
print("There are %s unique groups in the data" % len(df["group"].unique()))
# Group DataFrame by 'group' column
for i, group in df.groupby("group"):
    # Unique Subgroups in Group
    print("Group %d has %d unique subgroups" % (i, len(group["subgroup"].unique())))
    # Minimum value for a subgroup in group
    print("The minimum value for a subgroup in group %d is %0.1f" % (i, min(group["value"])))
    # Apply normalization / divide by min
    gnormed = group["value"] / min(group["value"])
    normed.extend(gnormed)
df["normed"] = normed
# See what the DataFrame looks like
print(df)
```

Which will output:

```
There are 3 unique groups in the data
Group 1 has 3 unique subgroups
The minimum value for a subgroup in group 1 is 356.0
Group 2 has 4 unique subgroups
The minimum value for a subgroup in group 2 is 478.0
Group 3 has 4 unique subgroups
The minimum value for a subgroup in group 3 is 388.0

    group  subgroup  value    normed
0       1         1    356  1.000000
1       1         2    403  1.132022
2       1         3    370  1.039326
3       2         2    488  1.020921
4       2         3    568  1.188285
5       2         4    562  1.175732
6       2         5    478  1.000000
7       3         1    415  1.069588
8       3         2    418  1.077320
9       3         3    388  1.000000
10      3         4    414  1.067010
```

Of course, you did ask for this in pure numpy. Here's one way you could do it:

```
data = {
    "group": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    "subgroup": [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    "value": [356, 403, 370, 488, 568, 562, 478, 415, 418, 388, 414]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Get Numpy Array from Pandas Object
array = df.values

# If you're not using Pandas, the relevant code starts here
# First, Get Unique Groups (with 0 as the index of the group column)
stacks = []
uniqueGroups = np.unique(array[:,0])
for groupIndex in uniqueGroups:
    # Get Group Data
    group = array[np.where(array[:,0] == groupIndex)]
    # Get Unique Subgroups (with 1 as the index of the subgroup column)
    uniqueSubgroup = np.unique(group[:,1])
    # Get Min Group Value (with 2 as the index of the values column)
    minVal = np.min(group[:,2])
    # Compute normed values
    normed = np.expand_dims(np.divide(group[:,2], minVal), 1)
    # Concatenate the normed values with the group array
    stacks.append(np.hstack((group, normed)))

# Concatenate groups back together with normed data and overwrite original numpy array
array = np.vstack(stacks)
# Print the example array
print(array)
```

Which will output:

```
[[   1.            1.          356.            1.        ]
 [   1.            2.          403.            1.13202247]
 [   1.            3.          370.            1.03932584]
 [   2.            2.          488.            1.0209205 ]
 [   2.            3.          568.            1.18828452]
 [   2.            4.          562.            1.17573222]
 [   2.            5.          478.            1.        ]
 [   3.            1.          415.            1.06958763]
 [   3.            2.          418.            1.07731959]
 [   3.            3.          388.            1.        ]
 [   3.            4.          414.            1.06701031]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned a lot and using the pandas code I build the whole script that analyses my whole data set.

Comment: Happy to help! If you consider this to be the answer, please accept it : )

Comment: Oh. Didn't know. I guess accept is that I press on the green "check field" next to the upper left of your answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess there may be a simpler way to do it but using `Pandas` is definitely the way to avoid time consuming loops.

**Step 1**: Stuff the numpy array into a pandas data frame

```
import pandas as pd
x = [[1,1,365], [1,2,403], [1,3,370], [2,2,488],[2,3,568],[2,4,562], [3,1,415], [3,2,418], [3,3,388], [3,4,414]]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ["group", "subgroup", "value"])
print(df)

   group  subgroup  value
0      1         1    365
1      1         2    403
2      1         3    370
3      2         2    488
4      2         3    568
5      2         4    562
6      3         1    415
7      3         2    418
8      3         3    388
9      3         4    414
```

**Step 2**: Run a `groupby` method to find the `value` corresponding to minimum subgroup in each group

```
min_df = df.loc[df.groupby(["group"])["subgroup"].apply(np.argmin)]
min_df = min_df.drop(["subgroup"], axis =1) # Remove subgroup from this new table.
min_df.columns = ["group", "value_to_divide"] # Name columns correctly
print(min_df)

   group  value_to_divide
 0      1              365
 3      2              488
 6      3              415
```

**Step 3**: Merge with original dataframe

```
df = pd.merge(df, min_df, how="left", on="group")
print(df)

   group  subgroup  value  value_to_divide
0      1         1    365              365
1      1         2    403              365
2      1         3    370              365
3      2         2    488              488
4      2         3    568              488
5      2         4    562              488
6      3         1    415              415
7      3         2    418              415
8      3         3    388              415
9      3         4    414              415
```

**Step 4**: Perform the division and convert back to numpy array, if needed

```
df["new_value"] = df.value/df.value_to_divide
print(df)

group  subgroup  value  value_to_divide  new_value
0      1         1    365              365   1.000000
1      1         2    403              365   1.104110
2      1         3    370              365   1.013699
3      2         2    488              488   1.000000
4      2         3    568              488   1.163934
5      2         4    562              488   1.151639
6      3         1    415              415   1.000000
7      3         2    418              415   1.007229
8      3         3    388              415   0.934940
9      3         4    414              415   0.997590

required = np.array(df[["group", "subgroup", "new_value"]])
```